# WxWidget based programs fail to refresh drawings

Tags: graphics, gui

I am trying to pinpoint a problem where WxWidget based programs (so far Audacity and the Gnuplot wxt terminal) fail to show and refresh content in their "plotting" part of the window. Main UX seems to work fine.

Here's an example:

[image: Audacity and GnuPlot not refreshing]

You can see that the part of the Audacity window where the recordings are does not refresh (this happens also during recording, making Audacity pretty much unusable). The same happens in the right side window marked by "Figure 1", which is spawned by running `gnuplot -p` with a wxt terminal.

As the only link between the two applications is WxWidgets, I think that it's where the trouble is; however I'm not sure what I can do about it.

SYSTEM INFO:

```
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
--------------------------------------------------
LXQt Desktop Toolbox - Technical Info
  LXQt About Version:     0.14.1
  LXQt Version:           0.14.1
  Qt:                     5.12.8
  Build type:             Release
--------------------------------------------------
Openbox 3.6.1
--------------------------------------------------
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev e7)
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
    Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
```

Comment: Very unclear. What are your: Ubuntu version, desktop environment, display server, video driver?

Comment: @N0rbert I have updated my question.